# Why render partial with collection wont work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is my code:
on my index.erb

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>Company</th>
    </tr>
    <% render partial: :company, collection: @companies %>
</tbody>
```

on my _company.erb:

```
<tr>
    <td><%= link_to company.name, company %></td>
</tr>
```

It won't show the data on the view.

Comment: It displays blank page?

Comment: Yes it does, with no error, the data won't show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change

```
<% render partial: :company, collection: @companies %>
```

to

```
<%= render partial: :company, collection: @companies %>
```

You are missing a `=`